# NSMutableArray containsObject method not detecting object

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

```
// Add the button to the NSMutableArray.
...
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[[self hBtns] addObject:btn];
...

// In another method, try to see if it exists.
- (void)didPushBtn:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
  if ([[self hBtns] containsObject:btn]) // Is false every time.
  ...
}
```

Why is it not detecting that the UIButton is in the array?

---

**EDIT**

It turns out that it won't even detect it right after it's added:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[[self hBtns] addObject:btn];
if ([[self hBtns] containsObject:btn]) // Returns false.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had forgotten to initialize the array (*doh*):

```
[self setHBtns:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0]];
```

Comment: That was actually going to be my next suggestion. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: You should also ensure that setHBtns: doesn't retain the array or you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Either that, or it **should** retain the array, and he could use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0]` (or just `[NSMutableArray array]`) instead. The bigger question in my mind is whether the property should be `readonly`, and the array should just be created once in the initializer of the containing class.

Comment: [slaps head]. Glad you shared the question and answer - the same problem was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the `isEqual:` comparison is failing. Can you take a look at the `hash` for the UIButton in both places (where it's added, and then in `didPushBtn`) and see if they're the same value?

Comment: Thanks for the help Meredith. The hashes are the same. Any other ideas on why the isEqual: comparison would fail?

Comment: Hey Meredith, see my edit to the question. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out (see below). Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it!